# What's the name of the ratio between successive moment of random variable?

Tags: random-variable, moments

Let $X$ be a random variable.

Is there a name to the ratio: $\frac{E[X^{n+1}]}{E[X^{n}]}$, where $E[\cdot]$ is the expectation of $\cdot$?

We let $n\ge0$ and for $n=0$ it's simply the expectation of the constant number $1$.

Specifically, what is the name of this ratio when $n=1$: $\frac{E[X^{2}]}{E[X]}$?

Is there a meaningful interpenetration for this value?

Comment: This ratio often does not exist (consider any centered random variable for instance). At a minimum, then, if anyone had ever chosen to name something like it, they likely would have studied $E[|X|^{n+1}] / E[|X|^n]$ instead.  In the case $n=2,$ your ratio has a simple algebraic relationship with the *coefficient of variation.*

Comment: and/or *index of dispersion*